# write() not writing correct amout of bytes on windows in C

Tags: c, windows, gcc, cl.exe

When writing values to a file in C under Windows, I'm getting something which seems to be wrong, and the result differs from the same program run in Cygwin.

In this case, I'm writing a float to a file:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <io.h>

int         main( void )
{
    int     fd;
    float   f;

    fd = open("file.a", O_RDWR | O_CREAT);
    f = (float)atof("-0.1352237");
    printf("%.7f\n", f);

    write(fd, (void *)&f, sizeof(float));
    close(fd);
    printf("sizeof(float): %d\n", sizeof(float));

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I've compiled and run this file on both Windows and in Cygwin (without the  include), and I'm not getting the same result. Since I'm writing a float, I would expect the output file to have 4 bytes written to it

However, the output when compiled with cl.exe in the command line, seems wrong:

```
1578 0d0a be
```

If I read from the file to a float, I'm not getting the correct value, obviously. And the amount of bytes written to the file is wrong to, it should only be 4 bytes, not 5.

This is what I get when running in Cygwin:

```
1578 0abe
```

This is correct. If I read this from the file to a float I get the correct value (-0.1352237).

Am I missing something here ? Are the windows implementation of those functions flawed ?
Or maybe I'm not writing the data properly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have opened the file in text mode (the default), so the `0a` (`"\n"`) is being translated to `0d0a` (`"\r\n"`).

You need to open the file in binary mode, using the `O_BINARY` flag.

Comment: What a basic mistake!
Thanks, that fixes the problem, and makes sense. But why is there a \n being written ? and it's being written between two bytes.

Comment: Because the ASCII value for `\n` is `0a` (i.e. 10 in decimal).  One of your bytes happens to have that value.

Comment: All right, makes sense, I see what I was doing wrong. Thanks.